# how to create relation between state and country so that only related stat show when select any country

Tags: python, django

I am making a form in which i need country state city relation.if i select any country then only its related state should show.
 my models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    countryId=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country

class State(models.Model):
    state_id=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state


class City(models.Model):
    cityid=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city
```

and views.py

```
class alldataviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    print "in views et"
    queryset=All.objects.all()
    serializer_class=AllSerializers
    print "before get"
    def list(self, request,*args):
        data=request.GET
        var=data.get('var')
        print"before if",var
        if var=='101':
            print "inside if"
            for i in range(1,42):
                print "inside for"
                print "states of india",i


        else:
            print "hahahha"

        return Response("serializer.data")
```

my views is working.but its will very lengthy if write like this.there is approx 260 country for my database.and approx 4200 states so if write whole code like my way ,then i have to write the code inside my views.py approx 4500 times. i think it not proper way.please let me know how can i write my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chained](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained.) jquery library.

Rewrite `render_option` for foreignkey field in forms.py:

Use the relation between yours models is One to Many use use `models.ForeignKey` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

Look at this [post](https://axiacore.com/blog/django-y-selects-encadenados/) for select joined.

Comment: For many thousandth child you can use ajax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611775/how-to-limit-the-choices-of-a-child-field-based-on-a-parent-fields-value/35638407#35638407